# Гистограмма элементов массива

Tags: c, массивы, сортировка, вывод, гистограммы

Дан массив из  чисел 0, 1, . . ., −1.
Постройте гистограмму значений элементов массива: для каждого значения подсчитайте
сколько раз оно встречается в массиве.
Для каждого значения, которое встречается в массиве хотя бы раз, выведите сколько раз
оно присутствует среди элементов массива в формате: “значение: количество”.
Значения требуется выводить в порядке возрастания.

Мой код считает цифры в несколько заходов, я не знаю как это исправить. Например массив 1 1 1 1 он посчитает 1-5 1-4 и т.д.

`#include <stdioh> int main() { int nums, count = 0; scanf("%d", &nums); int a[10001] = { 0 }`  {

```
for (int i = 0; i < nums; i++)
{
    scanf("%d", &a[i]);
}
for (int b = 0; b < (nums - 1); b++)
{
    count = 1;
    for (int c = b + 1; c < nums; c++)
    {
        if (a[b] == a[c])
        {
            count++;
        }
    }
    printf("a[b] - %d, count - %d\n", a[b], count);
}
return 0;
```

}

Comment: Диапазон значений известен? Какой? Массив такого размера можно создать? Если да — используйте его как счетчик...